# Is PARITY in QAC_0 (if that even makes sense)

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, quantum-computing, circuit-complexity

As is well known PARITY cannot be done in poly-sized constant-depth circuits, and in
fact const-dept circuits require EXP number of gates.

What about QUANTUM circuits?

a) Can PARITY be done with a quantum circuit that has constant depth and poly number of gates?

b) Does my question even make sense?

Comment: This seems relevant: http://eccc.uni-trier.de/eccc-reports/1999/TR99-032/

Answer (score 20):

The question makes sense, and the short answer is that it's an open problem.

Here's the long answer: Depending on how you define constant-depth unbounded-fanin quantum circuits, you might get different classes. QAC<sup>0</sup> is usually defined to have unbounded fanin Toffoli gates and single-qubit gates. QAC<sup>0</sup><sub>wf</sub> is the class where we also allow a "fanout" gate, which copies an input bit to many outputs. (It implements |a>|0>...|0> --> |a>|a>...|a>) This class is really powerful since it contains, besides PARITY and AC<sup>0</sup>, also ACC<sup>0</sup> and TC<sup>0</sup>.

So the obvious question to ask is whether PARITY is contained in QAC<sup>0</sup>, and this is an open problem. It is equivalent to asking whether QAC<sup>0</sup> = QAC<sup>0</sup><sub>wf</sub>. I guess that the belief is that PARITY is not in QAC<sup>0</sup>. Further information can be found in the survey [Small depth quantum circuits](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1272729.1272739) by Bera, Green and Homer.

Comment: Do you have a citation that shows that $TC^0 \subseteq QACC^0$?

Comment: @SamuelSchlesinger: This paper shows that you can compute threshold, parity, majority, etc. with only fanout gates and 2-qubit gates: http://www.theoryofcomputing.org/articles/v001a005/

Answer (score 10):

Surprisingly, the number of extra work qubits (ancilla) matters. Right now it is known that PARITY is not in QAC_0 with bounded ancillae. [Quantum lower bounds for fanout](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.9.9565) gives one proof for circuits using at most linearly many ancilla and 
[doi:10.1016/j.ipl.2011.05.002](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1994580) gives another proof for circuits using no ancillae.